# How do I fix the error "Can not access internal class" error in C#?

Tags: c#, reference

I am pretty much using existing code to create a new class in a new file. I am using existing code to create a test class. One of the declarations does not compile and gives me a red warning in Resharper stating:

> Cannot access internal class "..." here.

I am using the namespace where the class is defined. What else am I missing?

Comment: It is pretty unclear if you talk about your "existing code" or reusing of 3rd party assembly. In case of 3rd party assembly, stop using internal classes. If an author has decided to make it internal by design, then there were some reasons to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You should mark the class as `public` instead of `internal`.

Even if you use the appropriate namespace, it is reasonable why you get an error like this. The reason is that you **expose** an `internal` class through a `public` class, which is not allowed. A class that is `internal` can be accessed **only** by types in the assembly that the class is defined or by assemblies where the internal classes of an assembly can be viewed (please have a look at [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using .NET 5+, you can add this setting to your .csproj file to make internals of your app visible to another assembly (for instance to a test project):

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <InternalsVisibleTo Include="ProjName.Tests" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the AssemblyInfo.cs file, add the InternalsVisibleTo attribute and specify the name of your test project assembly. Replace YourTestProject with the actual name of your test project assembly:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("YourTestProject")]
```